# Aligning messageformat on printing a JTable

Tags: java, printing, jtable, messageformat

I'm using this for the moment to print out my table, and it works. But I'm not really happy with the layout of the messageformatting, I would like to have both pagenumber and date in the footer, and date format aligned to the left side of the table, and page to the right.

How can I do that? Been reading some stuff about overriding the PrintTable method, but seems to get pretty complex from what I've read.

Hope you can help me with this issue, thank you. :)

```
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.OrientationRequested;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import dk.beesys.rims.ui.WindowInventory;


public class Print {

   private static Print INSTANCE;

   public static Print getInstance() {
      if (INSTANCE == null) {
         INSTANCE = new Print();
      }
      return INSTANCE;
   }

private Print(){ }

    public void printList(java.awt.event.ActionEvent ignore) {
       String strDate = MessageFormat.format("{0,date,short} {0,time,short}", new Date());

        MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("- {0} -"); 
        MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Printed: " + strDate);
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        aset.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);

        try {

            WindowInventory.getInstance().getTable().print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer, true, aset, true);

        } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
            System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You might look at this [`CustomTablePrintable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894436/printing-headers-and-footers-in-color). You feed it your table's unadorned `getPrintable()` result. In your `PrinterJob`, the custom `print()` will image the table and then draw your footer in the same graphics context. You can use the context's boundary, `getFontMetrics()` and `stringWidth()` to determine where to draw your formatted strings.

Addendum: Here's an example of printing a gray date in the bottom right corner of each page:

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int index) throws PrinterException {
    if (index > 0) return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    String s = new Date().toString();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    table.getPrintable(
        JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, null, null).print(g2d, pf, index);
    Rectangle r = g2d.getClipBounds();
    int dw = g2d.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(s);
    int dh = g2d.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
    System.out.println(index + " " + r);
    g2d.setPaint(Color.gray);
    g2d.drawString(s, r.x + r.width - dw, r.y + r.height - dh);
    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

Addendum: While this approach works for a table that fits on a single page, this article describes printing [*Components Larger Than One Page*](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/advprint.html#mp).

Comment: Been trying to get it to work but without any luck. Any chance that anyone has a code example that would be easier to implement than the CustomTablePrintable example above?

Answer (score 0):

Been trying some things back and forth now and still not able to get anything to work. I know what I've pasted in here might be a bit (way) off, but it's the result of trying various things.

```
public class CustomTablePrint implements Printable  {

private static CustomTablePrint INSTANCE = null;

public static CustomTablePrint getInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new CustomTablePrint();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

private CustomTablePrint() {}


    @Override


    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat,  
            int pageIndex) throws PrinterException { 
        if (pageIndex > 0) { 
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE; 
        } 
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(WindowInventory.getInstance().getTable().getPrintable(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, null, null));



        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics; 
        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY()); 

        // Draw header/footer here

        String strDate = MessageFormat.format("{0,date,short} {0,time,short}", new Date());
        String printed = "Printed: ";

        graphics.drawString(printed + strDate, 10, 10); 

        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        aset.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
        job.printDialog(aset);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;         
    } 
}
```