# How can I "pack()" a printable Java Swing component?

Tags: java, swing, printing, layout-manager

I have implemented a Java Swing component that implements `Printable`. If I add the component to a JFrame, and do `this.pack();` on the JFrame, it prints perfect. But if I don't add the component to a JFrame, just a blank page is printed.

This code gives a great printout:

```
final PrintablePanel p = new PrintablePanel(pageFormat);
new JFrame() {{ getContentPane().add(p); this.pack(); }};
job.setPrintable(p, pageFormat);
try {
    job.print();
} catch (PrinterException ex) {
    System.out.println("Fail");
}
```

But this code gives a blank page:

```
final PrintablePanel p = new PrintablePanel(pageFormat);
// new JFrame() {{ getContentPane().add(p); this.pack(); }};
job.setPrintable(p, pageFormat);
try {
    job.print();
} catch (PrinterException ex) {
    System.out.println("Fail");
}
```

I think that `this.pack();` is the big difference. How can I do `pack()` on my printable component so it prints fine, without adding it to a JFrame? The panel is using several LayoutManagers.

I have tried with `p.validate();` and `p.revalidate();` but it's not working. Any suggestions? Or do I have to add it to a hidden JFrame before I print the component?

**UPDATE:** If I do `p.doLayout();` some parts are printed, but not the subcomponents. And from the documentation of [`doLayout()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#doLayout()):

> Causes this container to lay out its components. Most programs should not call this method directly, but should invoke the validate method instead.

But `p.validate();` is **not** working for me.

Comment: did you try to repaint it? Did you set the panel size??

Comment: Yes, the Size and PreferredSize is set in the constructor of the JPanel. But it doesn't help :(

Comment: what do you have on your panel?
components/image

Comment: besides what is that terrible with having a ghost frame for a sec?

Comment: @TacB0sS: I have many components, mainly JComponents, JLabels and JTextFields.

Comment: @TacB0sS: There is no `setBufferStrategy`-method in `JPanel`

Comment: sorry my friend I'm dry... you still didn't answer me about comment 3:"
besides what is that terrible with having a ghost frame for a the printing process?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`invalidate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#invalidate%28%29), which will cause [`validate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29) to invoke [`validateTree()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validateTree%28%29); alternatively, use [`validateTree()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validateTree%28%29) directly.

@TacB0sS seems to make a good point: simply  don't invoke [`setVisible()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible(boolean%29); this related [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865009) is cited for reference.

Comment: `validateTree()` is not a visible method. The reason to why `invalidate()` and `validate()` doesn't work is probably that they skip components that aren't visible.

Comment: You're right, `validateTree()` is `protected`. Any luck using `validate()` and rendering to a `BufferedImage`?

Comment: No, it looks like the component **needs** to be in a top level container to `validate()`. See [Why can't I validate a JComponent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362484/why-cant-i-validate-a-jcomponent/8362549#8362549)

Comment: Aha! `JFreeChart can render to a `BufferedImage` in headless mode, but it's not a `JComponent`.

Comment: Yes, render to an `BufferedImage` is no problem. Or just override `paintComponent()`. But my whole idea with this is to use a **LayoutManager** for creating "documents", so I don't have to write pixel values as with Java2D. And I need to call `validate()` so the Layout can do it's job.

Comment: That makes sense. Would the kind of document/flow layout effected by [`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) be an alternative?