# Text alignment in java printing

Tags: java, swing, printing, java-2d

I am using 2d graphics to print the string on to the paper. I want the string to be aligned on the paper like right, left, centre. How can I do that ?

Comment: by "paper", you mean...?

Comment: I don't think there is any built in mechanism to do that. You'll have to use `drawString(String str, int x, int y)` and knowing the paper width, do the coordinate math for the alignments and use them.

Comment: @mre: paper means the printing media..

Comment: @Bala R: ok fine.. but are u sure tat it is a good idea ? and is tat the only way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basic [Printing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html)

EDIT: [basic 2D Graphics stuff](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm) shows examples about PrinterJob, PrintJob and Print

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html), as @mKorbel suggests, you might look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311508/aligning-messageformat-on-printing-a-jtable/2313423#2313423) that prints the date in the bottom right corner of each page.