# JTable printing. How can I make fonts bigger?

Tags: java, swing, printing, fonts, jtable

I am trying to print a `JTable` with the standard `.print()` method.

I am using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144775/messageformat-header-footerformat-how-to-change-font-for-jtable-printing) thread and it works.

However the printed table appears with very small letters. My `JTable` has a font size of 14. I tried using much bigger fonts and there is a slight change in the printing result. However going over font size 16 the table on screen looks really ugly. So I need to modify printing font size.

Although I am printing using `JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH` table is not enlarged to fit printing area (ie in the case when printing in landscape mode).

this is my printing routine:

```
MessageFormat headerFormat = new MessageFormat(str1 +" FROM " + fromDateButton.getText() + " TO " + toDateButton.getText()+"");
MessageFormat footerFormat = new MessageFormat("- {0} -");                  
tbSchedule.print(javax.swing.JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, headerFormat, footerFormat);
```

So, my question is: How can I enlarge table to fit printing area or how can I print with bigger fonts than the ones the table on the screen has?

Comment: please did you tried workaround, [code (linked) in comment by @trashgod](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2313423/714968)

Comment: Hi, I am not referring to the header/footer fonts. I am talking about the font inside the table cells.

Comment: contents is about  `JTables printable` and  `Xxx.getFontMetrics(:-)`